Linear air resistance on a pendulum
I am investigating whether the air drag on a pendulum is linear. To test this, I used the solution to the differential equation of a damped pendulum(with $-kv$) and applied a Hilbert transformation to extract the exponentially decreasing amplitude. By plotting the logarithm of the amplitude versus time, I can determine the nature of the drag: if the plot forms a straight line with a negative slope, it suggests linear drag in that interval; otherwise, the drag is likely quadratic.
While I am aware of the role of the Reynolds number, I am exploring an alternative approach. However, I am uncertain why a straight line with a negative slope would necessarily indicate linear drag.

Isn’t a straight line linear? Maybe I’m misunderstanding the question….

yes, but the plot I am looking at is the logarithm of the amplitude not the air resistance. How does that imply that air resistance is linear? I just don't see the correlation.

If you’re looking at a log plot and there’s a straight line then that represents an exponential relationship, which makes sense if drag is proportional to $v$ linearly - a function whose derivative is linearly proportional to its own value is exponential.

You want to plot $log(A)$ vs $Log(t)$. Then the slope tells you about the power.
Suppose the law is $A = A_0t^n$ for some $n$. Take the $log$ of both sides. Then
$$log(A) = log(A_0t^n) = log(A_0) + n log(t)$$
Lets define these variables
$$lA = log(A)$$
$$lA_0 = log(A_0)$$
$$lt  = log(t)$$
Then
$$lA = lA_0 + nlt$$
The slope of the line is the power. The intercept is $log(A_o)$.
